# Baby Rudin Theorem 9.7a)

Tags: real-analysis

> If $A \in L(R^n, R^m)$, then $\|A\| < \infty$

To prove this, an inequality was used:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n |A\mathbf{e}_i| < \infty $$

where $\mathbf{e}_i$ are the basis vectors. Can anyone explain why this inequality is necessarily true?

Comment: It's a finite sum of finite numbers, so it is finite.

Comment: @slimmerikko how was it established that each number is finite?

Comment: These numbers are simply norms of vectors (namely the columns of $A$). He defines this somewhere in the first chapter.

Comment: @SeanLee Can you give an example of a number which is _not finite_?

Comment: @slimmerikko Sorry if I’m being pedantic, but the part which I’m “uncomfortable” with and was hoping you could help me with is this - how do we know that these norms are finite, since A has not yet been defined as a matrix? (I.e. what’s stopping one of the elements of the transformed vector to be infinity, in the same way that $0$ under the transformation $\frac{1}{x}$ might be? (Although I know this example isn’t a linear transformation) )

Comment: @SeanLee See my answer. We know that $Ae_i$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$!   Hence its norm is a real number.The situation you describe can't happen. Matrix multiplication does not contain any divisions, just sums and multiplications.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta thanks, I get the matrix multiplication part. However, at this stage, Rudin has yet to define a linear transformation as a matrix multiplication. This is the part I’m confused by.

Comment: Rudin does not even talk about matrix multiplication. The assumption is that $A$ is a linear transformation $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ (he writes $A \in L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$). Thus, given a vector $e_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ as input, you get a vector $A(e_i) = Ae_i \in \mathbb{R}^m$ as output. Is still anything unclear? It is customary to write $A e_i$ instead of $A(e_i)$ for linear maps, so it looks like matrix multiplication (which it is in some sense), but it is formally just evaluation of the linear map $A$ at $e_i$.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Ah I think that its clearer now - is this because its $\mathbb{R}^m$ instead of $\bar{\mathbb{R}}^m$?

Comment: Yes, that's why. Note also that $\overline{\mathbb{R}}^m$ is not a vector space in a sensible way and linear maps are maps between vector spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance, $\sum_{i=1}^n |Ae_i| < \infty$ is not an inequality, is just another way to write : $\sum_{i=1}^n |Ae_i|$ is a **finite** *number*.

Answer (score 1):

We have a linear transformation $A: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$. The map

$$\Vert \cdot \Vert : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^+: x=(x_1, \dots, x_m) \mapsto \Vert x \Vert:= \left(\sum_{i=1}^m x_i^2\right)^{1/2}$$

sends vectors to positive real numbers. In particular, $\Vert x \Vert < \infty$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Now, we have vectors $Ae_1, \dots, Ae_n \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Hence, applying this

$$\Vert A e_1 \Vert < \infty, \dots, \Vert Ae_n \Vert < \infty$$
and consequently,

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \Vert A e_i \Vert < \infty$$